# How to boot Ubuntu in a dynamic disk where windows 7 is installed

Tags: boot, wubi

My Windows got crashed when i installed Ubuntu 11.04 inside Windows previously.

http://www.dynamic-disk.com/disadvantage-of-dynamic-disk.html

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you use a fixed disk size for this installation. I can't imagine that wubi would be compatible with this. Given that you have to force Windows 7 to use a dynamic disk, and that you can extend and contract a basic partition in Windows, there is little benefit to the dynamic disk configuration.

Comment: Is there any software that can create a small basic partition from my dynamic disk? I can only create a simple volume using windows Computer management.

Comment: I don't know of any Windows tools. You could boot a live cd version of Ubuntu and use the disk utility found in the dash.